# Twitter Search In user_timeline.json

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, getjson

Am using jQuery to retrieve tweets in .json. One part of my application requires old tweets, and twitter search returns tweets only for last 6 days. This old tweets have to contain certain hashtag.
I know that user_timeline API method can return 3200 tweets, but i cant understand how to get 3200 tweets, loop through them and find tweets i need.
Here is what i have for now:

```
function TwitterAPI(){}
TwitterAPI.Statuses = function Statuses(){}

TwitterAPI.Statuses.hashed = function(username, hashtag, count, to, callback){
   requestURL = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23" + hashtag + "&rpp=" + count + "&from=" + username + "&to=" + to + "&callback=?";
   //requestURL =  "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?q=from:" + username + "+" + hashtag + "&perpage=1"
   $.getJSON(requestURL, callback);
  } 

var user_info = ["name", "birthday", "hobby", "homepage"];  
  $("#info ul li.userinfo").append('<img src="images/lilspinner.gif" />');
  $.each(user_info, function() {
   var hashtag = this;
   TwitterAPI.Statuses.hashed("<%= @profile.name %>", hashtag, 1, "twisnt", function(json, status){
    var content = "";
    $.each(json.results, function(i, info){ 
     text = info.text.replace( /(\#)\w+\b/,"").replace( /(\@)\w+\b/,"");
     if (hashtag == "homepage") {
      content = "<a style='display:none' href='"+text+"'>"+text+"</a>"; 
     }
     else {
      content = "<span style='display:none'>"+text+"</span>"; 
     }          
    });  
    $("li#" + hashtag).append(content);
    $("li#" + hashtag + " img").remove();
    $("li#" + hashtag + " *").fadeIn("slow");
   })
});
```

It does everything i need, but only when needed messages where tweeted in last 6 days,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the twitter API you can only get 100 results at a time. Use the rpp search item to request 100 and start on page 1. Then you can loop through pages getting 100 items at a time. Do this 15 times to get 1500 items. The reason for this is twitter only allows you to get the last 15 pages for a max of 1500 items.

Example:

```
var maxRpp = 100;

var i; //pages
for (i = 1;i <= 15; i++) {
     $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=pants&result_type=recent&page=' + i + '&rpp=' + maxRpp + '&callback=?',function(data){
          //do thing  
     });    
};
```

Source:
[Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search)